# Is there an "observable" set or list in Dart?

Tags: stream, dart, observable

I'd like to generate a stream of events from a common `Set<T>` object in dart so that I am informed whenever any `T` is added or removed. Is there anything like that already available in the core dart libraries or one of its packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are observable list and map in https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/observe.

Comment: cool, thanks! I wonder how they could implement an observable map without an observable set, but I will make it work. Thanks!